# Postgres, loading raster into db and visualize with qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, postgresql, raster2pgsql

I'm trying to import a TIF raster into a Postgres db using this command:

```
Raster2pgsql -s 26591 -I -C -e -Y -F –N -M C:\Users\Ivn\Desktop\Postgre_HOME\scratchmres1.tif -F | psql -U postgres -d ivndb -h localhost -p 5432
```

the command works but I can't add to display the raster in QGIS 2.10 PISA, I get the following warning:

[image]

And this messages in the registry:

> PG: dbname=ivndb host=localhost   port=5432 mode=2 schema=public column=rast table=geodb è un layer non valido - non

Can someone help me?

**SOLVED!** @Steven kay
[image]

Comment: It will probably be helpful if you can include the error in the text of the post as well as the picture. This will make it searchable. Also, it looks like it's complaining about an invalid layer, but a translation would be good as well.

Comment: I could reproduce this (Qgis 2.10.1) . Error in English is "geodb is an invalid layer - not loaded". Running qgis from terminal and looking at the console, I also saw  this :- ```ERROR 1: User parameter must be provided, or PGUSER environment variable must be set. Please set the user and try again.```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confimed (Ubuntu Pisa 2.10.1, 32 bit Ubuntu)

This might be a bug in Database Manager.

If you're on Ubuntu you can launch QGIS and see some additional error messages not available through the GUI. I saw this...

```
ERROR 1: User parameter must be provided, or PGUSER environment variable must be set. Please set the user and try again.
```

If you look at your log you'll see the GDAL Url which has been built to access the raster. It should look something like

```
PG: dbname=rastertest host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 mode=2 schema=public column=rast table=mytable
```

**There's no username or password in that URL, I suspect this is the problem.**

I thought that maybe those were redacted (hidden), but it looks like they're not being sent to the GDAL Driver.

Good news, though - you can work around it. Copy and paste the URL from the Error Log, and paste it into a text editor. Add your username and password, like so

```
PG: dbname=rastertest host=127.0.0.1 user=scott password=tiger port=5432 mode=2 schema=public column=rast table=mytable
```

Now, go to the Python console and import it from there...

```
rl = QgsRasterLayer("PG: dbname=rastertest host=127.0.0.1 user=scott password=tiger port=5432 mode=2 schema=public column=rast table=mytable", "testlayer")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rl)
```

That should allow you to pull the image out of the database. If no layer is added, make sure all your parameters are correct. If any of them are wrong, it won't throw an exception.

Comment: I raised this as [an issue on the QGIS tracker](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13594). This should be fixed in a future release, a fix was committed within an hour of reporting this... :-)